# QGIS attributetable: show $x and $y in other CRS than layer

Tags: field-calculator, coordinates

I have a point file with an attribute table. In the attribute table I am able to display the X and Y coordinates using the field calculator. These coordinates are in ETRS89. Because the end-user of the data uses a different system (EPSG:28992) I would like to display two more columns in my attribute table with the X and Y in EPSG:28992.

I thought I'd use the transform function but I can't get it to function. I would like the values to change if I move the location of the point in my chart.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by:
Setting the default value in the attributes form designer to:
x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:28992','EPSG:4326')) and checking the update box
This transforms from X in my native system to Longitude (WGS '84).
Did the same for y to Latitude (WGS '84).

I also wanted an extra two columns in my database with the proper nautical notation. Repeated the default trick by by setting the default of these columns to:
to_dm("[columname of Latitude in D,d]", 'y', 4)